# Grouped by table appended to empty dataframe only outputting the later columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a table that's been "grouped by" and I appended it to an empty dataframe, df_empty, then exported and saved to an Excel spreadsheet, but when it exports, the output is only showing the columns.

The following is an example dataframe, 'sample', of the kind of table I have. It's grouped by "team" and "position", but when I append it to df_empty by using `df_empty.append(sample)`, and then save it to Excel, it's only outputting the third column with the numeric values. How can I get it to export the 'team' and 'position' columns too? Hope this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Why are you appending to an empty df though?

Comment: I'm using a for loop to generate a different df for each month in the source dataset, so I created an empty dataframe to append the result of the loops to, if that makes sense.

Comment: Got you! So what I would assume the issue is is that the first two columns are indexes so they aren't appending properly. Try resetting the indexs before you append

Comment: I've tried  sample.reset_index(inplace=True), but it changes the dataframe to have multiple rows for team 'A', etc. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: And does that dataframe still look grouped when you print it?

Comment: Yea it's still in the same grouped order. I actually think this output works fine. Will stick with resetting the indices. Thanks for your help!